# Lower resolution of LVDS-0 in different aspect-ratio nVidia

Tags: debian, nvidia, xrandr

I am trying to clone 2 displays. I have a laptop with 1440x900 resolution and an external monitor with 1024x768 resolution. I want the laptop screen to show the same as the external monitor however, since the last update I cannot select a lower resolution for the laptop than it's native resolution of 1440x900 in nvidia-settings.

**Simply put, I want the laptop screen to display 1024x768 and cloned to the external monitor.**

I have looked into xrandr and came to the following commands, however this does not work. <strike>I am using the nVidia 302.17 driver at this moment.</strike> I have upgraded to 304.48, but the issue remains.

```
dennisf@anarki:~$ cvt 1024 768 60
# 1024x768 59.92 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 47.82 kHz; pclk: 63.50 MHz
Modeline "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync

dennisf@anarki:~$ xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync

dennisf@anarki:~$ xrandr --addmode LVDS-0 1024x768_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
```

Further information:

```
dennisf@anarki:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*+
   800x600        60.0  
   720x480        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
   640x400        60.0  
   512x384        60.0  
   7936x32636    137.6  
LVDS-0 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1440x900       60.1*+   60.1  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1024x768_60.00 (0x277)   63.5MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock   47.8KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock   59.9Hz
```

Thank you.

Comment: I assume a plain `xrandr --output TV-0 --same-as LVDS-0` (maybe without the `-0`) fails somehow?

Comment: The TV-0 max res is 1024x768, but LVDS-0 is 1440x900, so that doesn't really work. I can "clone" them in nvidia-settings, but only a part of LVDS-0 is shown on TV-0 (the top right corner, for example).

Comment: 5 minute edit limit: To clarify, here is a screenshot: http://snag.gy/RQA1M.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved with the latest drivers 331.20 by nVidia. All resolutions are now selectable from the nvidia-settings.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [`nvidia` doesn't support `xrandr` yet](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Using_Multiple_Screens#nvidia).

Thus you could follow the linked page's `xorg.conf` instructions or give [`disper`](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/) a try:

> Disper is an on-the-fly display switch utility. [...] Disper gives you the option to either **clone all detected displays**, or extend the desktop to them. Resolutions are automatically detected. For cloning, **the highest common resolution supported by all displays is chosen**; [...] At the moment **nVidia cards are supported**, and a basic XRandR backend is in place.

[Disper is packaged for Debian (testing, sid), too.](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=disper) <sup>(You could try [apt-pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html) if you're on stable.)</sup>

**Edit** [NVidia's 302 driver has XRandR support.](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA5NTY) [It's in testing/sid, too](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=nvidia-kernel-dkms) (but without backports to stable; apt-pinning is probably not an option here).

Comment: I have just upgraded to 304.48.